# How do you associate an action with a file type in Firefox 3.0 when the file is actually in xml format?

Tags: firefox, xml

How do you associate an action with a file type in Firefox 3.0 when the file is actually in xml format?  A program that I use has its own file extension, but actually stores its data in XML format.  What I want to be able to do is open these files from firefox and be allowed to associate them with the program that created them. However, instead of seeing a new file extension and asking me what to do with it, FF ignores the extension, automatically recognizes the content as XML, and just displays the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't pay much attention to the extension, it looks for the [mimetype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) that the webserver says the file is.

The webserver is probably saying the file is either `application/xml` or `text/plain` and so firefox will open the contents itself.

You could have the webserver use a nonstandard mimetype, then firefox would not know to open it, and would pass it to the OS or let you choose an action for it:

```
 Content-type: application/x-myapp
```